# How to retrieve the .xml extension attachments from mail by using MailCore to Sample iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, email, mailcore

How to retrieve the **.xml extension attachments** from mail by using **MailCore  for iphone**?

I used MailCore to download the attachments from my mail to my sample iPhone app. I getting  Inbox subjects from my mail that subjects I sort to get particular mail subject and  mail attachments.

The problem is I got particular mail subject but not attachments. I used below code to get attachments from mail but it's not working.

```
NSArray *Array=[msg attachments];
CTBareAttachment *ctbaratt=[Array objectAtIndex:0];
CTCoreAttachment *ctcoreatt=[ctbaratt fetchFullAttachment];
```

but I'm getting :

```
Array count is zero
```

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be for a few reasons:

1)It is possible that you're not downloading enough information about the CTCoreMessage. When making a request to download the CTCoreMessages you must specify what information you want by specifying the correct fetch attributes.

For example:

```
[core_folder messagesFromSequenceNumber:from to:to withFetchAttributes: CTFetchAttrEnvelope | CTFetchAttrBodyStructure]
```

should populate the information about the attachments.

When fetching a message from IMAP, the command will specify exactly what information it wants.

you can see what is being fetched by enabling MailCore Logging as follows:

```
MailcoreEnableLogging();
[core_folder messagesFromSequenceNumber:from to:to withFetchAttributes: CTFetchAttrEnvelope | CTFetchAttrBodyStructure];
MailcoreDisableLogging();
```

You will see commands of the format

```
<command number> <UID> <Command> (<requested structure>)
```

I imagine you will see something like this:

```
1 UID FETCH (ENVELOPE)
```

You should ensure that inside the () either BODY or BODY[2] or RFC822 as these will contain information about attachments.

When you see what is actually being fetched you can [read the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5), if you are dealing with mailcore and IMAP then it is well worth the investment in time.

2)Failing that, perhaps your CTCoreAccount and/or CTCoreFolder are not connected, thus preventing the CTCoreMessage from having a valid mailimapsession and being unable to download the attachment information. If an attribute inside a CTCoreMessage is not available then libetpan should download it on request. The fact that is it not suggests that your account or folder may be not valid or connected.

Comment: How I retrive the particular mail from my mail by using Mailcore..for example sending the parameters linke particular subject, to address or bwt dates like that..is it possible from MailCore.. So far I refd. these two method only to not particular all mails from Inbox,1.[self.Folder_inbox messagesFromSequenceNumber:1 to:0 withFetchAttributes: CTFetchAttrEnvelope | CTFetchAttrBodyStructure]; ,2.[self.Folder_inbox messagesFromUID:1 to:0 withFetchAttributes:CTFetchAttrBodyStructure]; there any specific method to retrive the particular mail . please share your ideas it's help me

Comment: If you want to retrieve the attachments from the inital fetching tof the CTCoreMessage then you must set "CTFetchAttrEnvelope | CTFetchAttrBodyStructure" as the fetch attributes. Your comment seems to suggest a different question entirely, namely 'how do i search for a particular message'. For this you would be better served asking this as a seperate question on here as it is a complex answer completely unrelated to this post.

Comment: @ JConway... thanks man... if you have idea? please share....for how do i search for a particular message  with MailCore...?